# Could i move the node_modules into public folder?

Tags: php, laravel

I have install Select2 which is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. And I tried to install but found it not under the public folder.

Let say I using  which mean I know the folder are under 'public' and then go to the subfolder as shown:

So the problem is node module are not under 'public' foler, could I move it whole folder into public?

Comment: build your front-end scripts in `resources/js` and then compile them by webpack. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem when doing that. `node_modules` is just a folder that keeps the dependencies organized.
However, the BEST way would be to compile all `js` assets into `app.js` file and include `app.js` into your public site.
AFAIK This can be done with grunt task or webpack (more modern approach).
there are also multiple solutions for this problem, like rollup.js: 
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en